# Aborting function execution if it's taking too long to run

Tags: javascript

Can you abort the execution of a JavaScript function if it's taking too long? If so, how?

ie. I call a synchronous `doStuff()` and if it does not return within an allotted amount of time, it's aborted and execution continues as if it did return.

Comment: Probably not... Impossible to answer without specifics.

Comment: Question is too broad..

Comment: You can modify `doStuff()` to keep track of the time its consumed and exit itself after surpassing the limit. Otherwise, no, you can't interrupt one function from another without control of multiple threads or processes, which JavaScript in general doesn't have an API for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with synchronous code (unless you exit the synchronous function from the code inside that function). But you can use promises to achieve what you want in an elegant manner. It's like calling a function asynchronously, and since the resolution is asynchronous, it can be interrupted after a timeout. See [how promises work on MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), on [David Walsh blog](https://davidwalsh.name/promises), and [on promisejs](https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/). The later also with some examples around interrupting the promise (see the `Promise.race` code). There is plenty of information on the internet if you search for it.